# asp.net mvc Testing Model Returned by controller ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

From controller `Action`:

```
return PartialView("Page1",obj);
```

Now in the `MVC` testing I have to test whether obj is an instance of `CLASS: ClassObj`

I am trying

```
var actualResult=controller.getObj();
Assert.IsInstanceOf(ClassObj,actualResult,"Fail");
```

but problem is actualResult is PartialViewResult.
How can i get model from it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the ViewData property of the result object.

from controller:

```
ViewData["data"] = obj;
```

in the test:

```
var result = controller.Action();
Assert.IsOfType<PartialViewResult>(result);

var data = ((PartialViewResult)result).ViewData["data"];
```

Or if the view is typed, then you might access the model directly. (I'm not exactly sure about the code, you need to test it).

```
var data =  (ViewPage<ModelType>((PartialViewResult)result).View).Model;
```

Comment: if the view is typed, then you might access the model directly?? How this is done?

Comment: There will be a Model field. I'll try to add it to the example.